# Trace for $L^\infty$ functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral

I'm considering the following problem. Let $s\in L^\infty ((0,T)\times K)$ for some compact $K\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be given. Consider the Steklov average in time of $s$, i.e. for $h>0$ and $t\in(0,T-h)$ define

$$s_h(x,t)=\int_t^{t+h} s(x,\tau) d\tau$$
and choose $s=0$  for $t>T$. Now let $f$ be some smooth function in $(0,T)\times K$. Due to the Steklov average $s_h \in H^1(0,T;L^\infty(\Omega))$.
Hence it is allowed to write for almost every $sigma\in (0,T-h)$

$$\int_K s_h(x,\sigma)f(x,\sigma) dx $$.Of course I want to send $h\to 0$.
Now $s_h\to s$ at least in $L^2((0,T)\times \Omega)$. So for a subsequence we find pointwise convergence.
Then formally we find for that subsequence and a.e. $t\in (0,T)$ that
$$\int_K s_h(x,\sigma)f(x,\sigma) dx \to \int_K s(x,t) f(x,t) $$.

But I don't get the justification for this: $s$ does not have a trace so it can be changed arbirtrarily in $t$. So the integral on the right hand side might be different for any representative of $s$ might even depend on the subsequence. (for each representative the subsequence might be different I think).

Any clues on that or do I understand something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost every point of $(0,T)\times K$ is a Lebesgue point for $s$. By Fubini's theorem, for almost every $t$ the set of Lebesgue points  has full measure in $\{t\}\times K$. This allows the trace of $s$ on $\{t\}\times K$ to be defined in a natural way, using some form of limit of averages as in your post.

The set of such $t$ depends on function $s$, of course. If you fix $t$ and vary $s$ over $L^\infty((0,T)\times K)$, there is no natural way to assign an element of $L^\infty(\{t\}\times K)$ to every element of $L^\infty((0,T)\times K)$.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really get the intention of your last sentence.

Comment: For the first part, I also thought of Lebesgue points. However, I think I mixed up that though $s$ does not have a trace it has values in certain points (i.e.) Lebesgue points. Hence an evaluation there can be possible but there is somehow no relation to trace theorems.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 The intention of my last sentence is to address your comment "there is somehow no relation to trace theorems". In a trace theorem we have a slice of space on which we want to "evaluate" some function space. This does not work with $L^\infty$. Even though every element of $L^\infty$ has well-defined values on almost every slice, those slices depend on which element of $L^\infty$ we take.

Comment: Tanks, somehow i was missing the word representative and probably just misunderstood the "vary over $s$". Thanks for the clarification